# What kind of E is this? (What is this type of variation called?)

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions

This monday, as I started my 'song a week' routine, I came up with this lovely chord progression (listed below). It is clearly some form of E, and I could go as far as to say it's a major scale. (The chords were named with the help of an app so I committed no mistakes).

```
Eb-F-Bb-F-G (listed as Ebadd9)
D-F-Bb-F-G (listed as Gm7/D)
C#-F-Bb-F-G (listed as Bbm6/C#)
C-Eb-G-Bb (listed as Cm7)
```

As it is evident, the first three chords vary only at the 'bass note' (?), with Eb, D and then C#. The fourth chord was an attempt to alleviate the tension and direct it to the root.

Is there a name for this type of variation? Has this scale a formal name?

---

When it ends, the last chord I play is a lone D7 (D-F#-C-D-A) to create unresolved tension. Should I play a Ddim7 instead, for theory purposes?

Comment: Looks more like a modulation from Eb or Bb to F, to diminished, and so on.

Comment: Is it relevant that it is the only chord progression I have during the whole song? (the song is three verses long)

Comment: Never do anything for theory purposes. Alway do the thing that *sounds* right.

Comment: That 3rd chord should have been called Bbm6/Db. Where did you source it?

Comment: "The chords were named with the help of an app so I committed no mistakes" The (big) mistake you make was assuming the app understood what was going on musically. These aren't "chords that need to be named" - they are a single chord, over a moving bass line. The names don't tell you anything useful about their *function* - apparently, the app is just finding the "best" name for each combination of notes, taken out of the context of the rest of the music.

Comment: No, no. You got me wrong. I used the app so I committed no mistakes at naming the notes. I understand that the names may vary depending on the context. As a proof I could tell you that the third chord is also a C#dim7 or Dbdim7 (again, it depends on context). I'm showing you the 'raw' info because I hope you can judge better than I can.

Comment: Except there is  an error! And the 3rd chord cannot be a dim anything.

Comment: @condosz I'm a little confused by your question. What do you mean by "kind of E"? Are you thinking this is an E scale, or an E key of some kind?

Comment: @Richard Well, yes, that's what I think... It isn't?

I really want to understand why what I did works so well. I don't have a really solid idea of what I just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'I could go as far as to say it's a major scale'?  There's a descending chromatic scale in the bass.   That's a very strong element in the progression, so much so that it would be surprising if the scale didn't continue at least as far as Bb. The bass line is so strong that it would justify almost any harmonies that fitted it.   Even the simplistic planing chords in my second example.   Though I feel we're travelling towards a tonic at the Bb this time.   What do you think?

Beware of chord-naming 'apps'.  Chord naming is often very much affected by context.  And yours has made one glaring mistake - how can a Bbm6 chord possibly include C#?   I could be cruel and say that if you don't see why it has to be Db, you're not ready to start analyzing harmony.  But I won't  :-)

[image]

Comment: It looks like "Bbm6/C#" means a Bb minor sixth with an added C#.  So, perhaps the chord app has simply failed to analyze the enharmonic Db when the input is a C#.  On the other hand, if that is the case, "Gm7/D" would seem to be a definite mistake, since it is saying that the D is a non-chord tone.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how slash chord names work.    And you prove the point that a chord-naming app is only useful to a person who knows enough not to need one!

Comment: Ok, I looked it up and yes, I did misunderstand.  Slash chord names basically serve the same purpose as figured bass, without having to write the bass note.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a chromatic move, down to a major 7, then to dominant 7, ending with the relative minor, all with added notes. The last chord is going to be entirely up to you and your ears. Theory will try to explain what's happening, after. It usually does a good job. But ears do it better...